# How to load a View Controller SubClass with a nib without specifying the nib name as a string?

Tags: ios, swift, nib

When you load a UIViewController Subclass programmatically, any nib associated with that ViewController will not be loaded if you named any of the files a different name than your subclass.

The only way to load the nib automatically, without passing a string name to the initializer, is to make sure your `x.nib` and `class.swift` has the same name as the `SubClass`.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the documentation, you actually can load a nib based view controller without naming it exactly the same thing. Although matching names is the most common way to do this, there's a second case, which should work even with Swift.

From [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/nibName):

> If you use a nib file to store your view controller's view, it is
>   recommended that you specify that nib file explicitly when
>   initializing your view controller.
>
> However, if you do not specify a
>   nib name, and do not override the loadView method in your custom
>   subclass, the view controller searches for a nib file using other
>   means. Specifically, it looks for a nib file with an appropriate name
>   (without the .nib extension) and loads that nib file whenever its view
>   is requested. Specifically, it looks (in order) for a nib file with
>   one of the following names:
>
> 1. If the view controller class name ends with the word ‘Controller’, as in MyViewController, it looks for a nib file whose name matches the
>      class name without the word ‘Controller’, as in MyView.nib.
> 2. It looks for a nib file whose name matches the name of the view controller class. For example, if the class name is MyViewController,
>      it looks for a MyViewController.nib file.

Comment: I can confirm this, you can name the class file whatever you like. As long as the class and Nib match these criteria.